# Read file with various white spaces in R

Tags: r, csv

I want to read this file into R

https://earthquake.usgs.gov/data/centennial/centennial_Y2K.CAT
I copy & pasted the text on the website into `Sublime` and saved it as a `.csv`

```
quakes <- read.table(file = "./anss/centinnel.csv",  
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                     sep = "", 
                     header = FALSE)
```

the `sep = ""` in `read.table()` should handle multiple whitespaces automatically... However, I get

> Row 1 does not have 27 elements.

Whats going wrong?

Comment: I usually work with USGS data. I recommend using fixed width option in excel. One more thing, you don't need to copy paste to cvs. You can read a webpage to r using `USGS.eq <- readLines('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/data/centennial/centennial_Y2K.CAT')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fixed-width file. Each column spans a specific number of characters. You can't assume that white space is a reliable separator, because it appears that missing data is simply left blank (a big stretch of white space). For example, row 4 has several values that are simply blank in rows 1-3.

You can use `read.fwf` to read this file correctly. You have to specify the width of each column, in characters. The following is my (quick) best guess at the column widths, but you will want to verify these yourself:

```
new.df <- read.fwf(
    'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/data/centennial/centennial_Y2K.CAT', 
    widths = c(5, 8, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 10, 8, 6, 4, 4, 4, 3, 7, 3, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 6, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3)
)
```